# Select with input field HTML/Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to have an input field with an arrow on the right so when I press on the arrow I have the bahaviour of a select tag ( a dropdown list of options). I was wondering if it's possible to do this in HTML/Angular 6... I found the solution of a datalist but it's not actually the result I'm looking for because with this solution if I enter some value in the input, which is not present in the datalist, and then click on the arrow anything display because datalist filters what to display depending on the input value.

Hope it's clear enough.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: Are you okay using libraries?

Comment: There are a cornucopia of widget libraries and frameworks out there that provide this, have you searched for those?

Comment: Yes I can use libraries and I looked for some but I couldn't find one interesting do you know one you could suggest me who does the job?

Answer (score 0):

Taking account that you can use a library or an UI framework, I suggest you the following options:

**Angular Material Select Component**

The google's UI framework to Angular applications.

**Pros**: Acessbility and responsivity are concerns of the framework, easy integration with Angular

**Cons**: The values of select can't be filtered

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

**Angular Material Autocomplete component**

Another component of google's UI framework. It's not a pure select, but it can be adapted as a combobox with filtering.

**Pros**: Acessbility and responsivity are concerns of the framework, easy integration with Angular

**Cons**: As it's not a pure select component, so maybe you would have to adapt it.

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview